# Tastypie-django custom error handling

Tags: django, error-handling, tastypie

I would like to return some JSON responses back instead of just returning a header with an error code. Is there  a way in tastypie to handle errors like that?

Comment: figured it out eventually. Here's a good resource to look at, if anyone else needs it. https://gist.github.com/1116962

Comment: If you can, clean this up and make it an Answer to help out the community

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out eventually. Here's a good resource to look at, if anyone else needs it. http://gist.github.com/1116962

```
class YourResource(ModelResource):

    def wrap_view(self, view):
        """
        Wraps views to return custom error codes instead of generic 500's
        """
        @csrf_exempt
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                callback = getattr(self, view)
                response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)

                if request.is_ajax():
                    patch_cache_control(response, no_cache=True)

                # response is a HttpResponse object, so follow Django's instructions
                # to change it to your needs before you return it.
                # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/
                return response
            except (BadRequest, ApiFieldError), e:
                return HttpBadRequest({'code': 666, 'message':e.args[0]})
            except ValidationError, e:
                # Or do some JSON wrapping around the standard 500
                return HttpBadRequest({'code': 777, 'message':', '.join(e.messages)})
            except Exception, e:
                # Rather than re-raising, we're going to things similar to
                # what Django does. The difference is returning a serialized
                # error message.
                return self._handle_500(request, e)

        return wrapper
```

Answer (score 4):

You could overwrite tastypie's `Resource` method [`_handle_500()`](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/af3dfaaafc57f502be7a945bcb6918fe5215fe78/tastypie/resources.py#L268). The fact that it starts with an underscore indeed indicates that this is a "private" method and shouldn't be overwritten, but I find it a cleaner way than having to overwrite `wrap_view()` and replicate a lot of logic.

This is the way I use it:

```
from tastypie import http
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie.exceptions import TastypieError

class MyResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
        fields = ('my', 'fields')

    def _handle_500(self, request, exception):

        if isinstance(exception, TastypieError):

            data = {
                'error_message': getattr(
                    settings,
                    'TASTYPIE_CANNED_ERROR',
                    'Sorry, this request could not be processed.'
                ),
            }

            return self.error_response(
                request,
                data,
                response_class=http.HttpApplicationError
            )

        else:
            return super(MyResource, self)._handle_500(request, exception)
```

In this case I catch all Tastypie errors by checking if `exception` is an instance of `TastypieError` and return a JSON reponse with the message "Sorry, this request could not be processed.". If it's a different exception, I call the parent `_handle_500` using `super()`, which will create a django error page in development mode or `send_admins()` in production mode.

If you want to have a specific JSON response for a specific exception, just do the `isinstance()` check on a specific exception. Here are all the Tastypie exceptions:

https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/exceptions.py

Actually I think there should be a better/cleaner way to do this in Tastypie, so I [opened a ticket](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/985) on their github.